Offset line and polyline
I am making a QGIS plugin for shortest path and I want to offset line for that shortest path. I am getting shortest path but not offset line. I've pasted code. Could you go through it and suggest something?

 #path_elements is collection of points
    geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(path_elements)
    feat.setGeometry(geom)  
    sink.addFeature(feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert) 

    fet = QgsFeature()
 #Dir = float(self.dlg.ui.radLeft.isChecked()
    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
    Lexists = False
    vl = None  # Initialize vl outside the loop
    pr = None

    # Check to see if the virtual layer already exists
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.name() == "test-layer":
            Lexists = True
            vl = layer
            pr = vl.dataProvider()
            vl.startEditing()
            break

    # If it doesn't exist, create it
    if not Lexists:
        # Create the layer
        vl = QgsVectorLayer("Linestring", "test-layer", "memory")
        pr = vl.dataProvider()
        vl.startEditing()

    # Assuming path_geometry is defined elsewhere
    #nline = path_geometry.parallel_offset(2.0, 'right', resolution=16, join_style=1, mitre_limit=10.0)

    # Convert QgsGeometry to Shapely LineString
    line = LineString(geom.asPolyline())


    # Check if the line is multi-part
    if line.is_empty or not line.is_simple or line.geom_type.startswith('Multi') or  line.geom_type.startswith( 'LineString') :
        # Iterate over each part
        for part in line.geoms:
            # Perform parallel offset for each part
            nline = part.parallel_offset(2.0, 'right', join_style=1, mitre_limit=10.0)
            # Convert Shapely LineString back to QgsGeometry and add it to your output
            nline_qgis = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(x, y) for x, y in nline.coords])
            # Use nline_qgis as your new geometry
    else:
        # If it's a single-part geometry, perform parallel offset directly
        nline = line.parallel_offset(2.0, 'right', join_style=1, mitre_limit=10.0)
        # Convert Shapely LineString back to QgsGeometry
        nline_qgis = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(x, y) for x, y in nline.coords])
        # Use nline_qgis as your new geometry

    # Create a new feature
    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(str(nline_qgis)))
    #fet.setAttributes([2.0, 'right', 1])

    # Add the feature to the provider
    pr.addFeatures([fet])

    # Commit changes if the layer is new
    if not Lexists:
        vl.commitChanges()



In the case you "create" the layer, you probably need to add the layer to your map:
if not Lexists:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

Also you need to commitChanges() in both cases:
vl.commitChanges()
if not Lexists:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)


